# VSCode, how can I change the default terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal, visual-studio-code, gnome-terminal

I don't use gnome, and thus don't use gnome-terminal, but VSCode REALLY wants me to. I scaffolded out a new asp.net web project and can run it just fine from my terminal using 'dnx run', but trying to use 'dnx: web' inside VSCode tries to launch gnome-terminal, which obviously fails. Can anyone help me out on this?

Comment: Note that I located **workbench.main.js** which appears to be the file that is referenced to open the terminal, however changing "**usr/bin/gnome-terminal**" to "**usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator**" didn't help. I didn't get any errors, but no terminal opened either...

Comment: I also tried "**usr/bin/lxterminal**" but that didn't work either...

Answer (score 0):

You may have found an answer by now, but for those who come across this question, there is now an integrated terminal in Visual Studio Code (June 2016)

The integrated terminal can be accessed with the shortcut **Ctrl+`** or by clicking on **Integrated Terminal** in the view menu.

By default it will use the Windows Command prompt, but if you are running the latest Windows 10 build you can easily switch to the new bash terminal by adding the following entry in your user settings.json file:

```
{
    ...
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "\\WINDOWS\\sysnative\\bash.exe"
}
```

Or, you can add the path to powershell, git bin, cygwin, whatever you may prefer.

See more details here:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal

Comment: I'm not convinced that's an answer. You've specified how to change the default 'shell'.